# How to get the previous date ( dd/mm/yy) in flutter

Tags: flutter, date

I would like to display the previous date
How do I do that?

i used this methode for display the date of today, i also want to display the previous date.

```
  static final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  static final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
  final String formatted = formatter.format(now);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final now = DateTime.now();
final today = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
final yesterday = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day - 1);
final tomorrow = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add or subtract values

```
DateTime today = DateTime.now();
DateTime fiftyDaysAgo = today.subtract(const Duration(days: 50));
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html